# Migrate Windows 10 Home to a virtual machine

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint

I dual boot Linux Mint and Windows 10 on my laptop, which is used for office, video, and browsing. Mint does most of what I need, but OpenOffice doesn't quite meet my needs nor does AutoCAD work in Linux. I would very much like to run the laptop as a Mint only machine and have been considering running AutoCAD & Office 365 Home inside a VM, thus getting the benefits of both worlds. Is there a way to use the existing Windows 10 licence to create a VM inside the Mint system, thus having Word, Excel, and AutoCAD essentially as icons within Mint?

Other how-to solutions involve a second licence. Is the current licence unusable?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the processor is an Intel Core i5.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting the VM on Linux, then you can use your single Windows license to install Windows in the VM (just remove all other installs/copies of it from the machine first).

Comment: Thanks Techie007.  So if I am understanding you correctly, I wipe the win 10 partition, then install to vm.  Time to get my hands dirty, thanks for the assist